# JPA hibernate one to many relationship creates extra column name

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities. I want to cascade the insertion of the child entity when the owner entity is persisted and set the SSO_ID of the child entity to the one that was generated for the owner by the generator.

```
@Entity(name = "USERS")
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "ID_GENERATOR")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "ID_SEQUENCE")
    @Column(name = "SSO_ID")
    private Long ssoId;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<UserEmail> userEmails = new ArrayList<>();

    // getters, setters etc.
}

@Entity(name = "USER_EMAILS")
@Table(name = "USER_EMAILS")
@IdClass(UserEmailId.class)
public class UserEmail {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "SSO_ID")
    private Long ssoId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "USER_MAIL")
    private String userMail;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "START_DATE")
    private Date startDate;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "EMAIL_TYPE")
    private String emailType;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private User user;

    // getters, setters etc.
}
```

The `UserEmail` ID class is:

```
public class UserEmailId implements Serializable {

    private Long ssoId;
    private String userMail;
    private Date startDate;
    private String emailType;

    // getters, setters etc.
}
```

Instead, I get an error:

> insert into hub_users_emails (user_sso_id, email_type, sso_id, start_date, user_mail) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
>
> (etc.)
>
> binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [1234837655] => this is user_sso_id
>
> (etc.)
>
> binding parameter [3] as [BIGINT] - [null] => this is the original sso_id
>
> SQL Error: 904, SQLState: 42000
>
> o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ORA-00904: "USER_SSO_ID": invalid identifier

I've tried some other setups of one to many (bidirectional, unidirectional, etc.) but It seems that this problem persists between all implementations.

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you use @ManyToOne and @OneToMany, hibernate will create user_sso_id on your USER_EMAILS table. I am not sure why do you want another  ssoId on USER_EMAILS. 
I have removed sso_id from USER_EMAILS and now it's working fine. I know this is not the exact answer of your question. Following code may help you.

```
@Entity(name = "USERS")
@Table(name = "USERS")
@Setter
@Getter
public class User {

 @Id
 @SequenceGenerator(name = "ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "ID_SEQUENCE")
 @GeneratedValue(generator = "ID_GENERATOR" )
 @Column(name = "SSO_ID")
 private Long ssoId;

 @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "user")
 private List<UserEmail> userEmails = new ArrayList<>();

}



@Setter
@Getter
@Entity(name = "USER_EMAILS")
@Table(name = "USER_EMAILS")
@IdClass(UserEmailId.class)
public class UserEmail {


 @Id
 @Column(name = "USER_MAIL")
 private String userMail;

 @Id
 @Column(name = "START_DATE")
 private Date startDate;

 @Id
 @Column(name = "EMAIL_TYPE")
 private String emailType;

 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 private User user;

}


@Setter
@Getter
public class UserEmailId implements Serializable {

  private String userMail;
  private Date startDate;
  private String emailType;

}


public class SomeClass{ 

 public User saveUser(){
     User user = new User();
     UserEmail userEmail = new UserEmail();
     userEmail.setUser(user);
     userEmail.setEmailType("type");
     userEmail.setStartDate(new Date());
     userEmail.setUserMail("someEmail@gmail.com");
     user.setUserEmails(Arrays.asList(userEmail));
     userRepo.save(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `sso_id` is part of the primary key in the `user_emails` table. Removing it is not an option. It's also the only way to connect the record to the `users` table.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your answer at first. Now I get It.